# Twitter Bootstrap Radio Toggle - Works in all browsers except IE9

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, internet-explorer-9

Working on some radio buttons for twitter bootstrap and the html and js in this example work great:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio" >
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="button">
    Public
    <input type="radio" name="is_private" value="0" />
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="button">
    Private
    <input type="radio" name="is_private" value="1" />
  </button>
</div>​


$('div.btn-group button').click(function(){
    alert($(this).children('input[name="is_private"]').val());
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XYEjs/31/

The problem is that I can't make this example (or my code, for that matter) work in IE9.  Instead of returning a value, it returns 'undefined.'

This example seems to work correctly (meaning it returns the value assigned in the html) in all other browsers (or at least all browsers I have tried...Chrome, Safari, Firefox)...and even works in IE8 and IE10.

It just won't work in IE9.  Thoughts?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: IE9 :( Strange error, so many experiences weirdness with IE9 and jquery. What version of jquery? MS claims above 1.5.1 should be ok http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh180175(v=vs.85).aspx - have you tried forcing a compatibilitymode, eg x-ua-compatible IE=Edge or similar?

Comment: Thanks...@davidkonrad I've tried it with Jquery 1.7.2 and 1.8.2.  Neither of those seems to make a difference in IE9.  I did try forcing the compatibility mode, but it didn't work.  Although it's possible I wasn't doing that right.  I'll take another look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is a bit late but I've just faced the same issue. The problem is that IE9 apparently doesn't like inputs inside buttons. I've just replaced buttons with s and it works. Spent the whole day on that stupid thing.

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="buttons">
    Public
    <input type="radio" name="is_private" value="0" />
</a>
```